# connecting to archive.ubuntu.com takes too long

Tags: networking, apt

I have a Ubuntu 11.10 server that I just installed fresh. Now if I try to do anything with `apt-get`, it tries to connect to `archive.ubuntu.com` .. It stays at `[Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a)]` phase for like 2 minutes, after which it actually starts to communicate and download stuff ...

Eventually it always connects, but in waits at the `[Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a)]` phase everytime for like 2 minutes !

I didn't have this problem previously on Ubuntu 11.10, right after reinstalling the OS ..

Any ideas on what the problem might be ?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact you're using IPv6.  Are you on an IPv6 network?

Comment: No I don't think so. I haven't configured any such thing ..

Comment: The IPs in your included messages is IPv6.  That suggests it's using IPv6, and if I"m not mistaken there aren't that many IPv6 servers for the archive.

Comment: @Ahmad Since you've solved your problem and have written the solution, please [post it as an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (and then you can edit it out of your question, too). Please note that you do not need to wait to do this; [only users with less than 100 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) must wait before answering their own questions. You can even mark your own answer as accepted (though for that you must wait until two days after you posted the question have passed).

Comment: Done .. Now I just have to wait for 22 hours in order to be able to accept my own answer :)

Comment: Ran into same problem, it seems to be pretty common. Nothing worked for me, except a trivial reboot.

Answer (score 89):

I solved this on 12.10 by editing **/etc/gai.conf** and uncommenting the line:

```
#
#    For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
#
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

This lets you keep IPv6 enabled, but sets the order of precedence to prefer IPv4 over IPv6.

Comment: Im not supposed to write ty as a comment but i think it ought be said ur my hero tytytytytyty

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 13.10 as well.

Comment: This is the answer

Comment: I signed up for the site just to upvote this.  Is this not broken for more people?  I'm surprised it's not a common issue, since it's gotten to the point of being a problem for every new installation of ubuntu I do.

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 14.04/ElementaryOS freya as well!

Comment: perfect! worked a charm!

Comment: Still valid for Xubuntu 15.04

Comment: Why does this work? (just needed to use the solution for 16.04)

Comment: Again with the thanks, but the question is, why is this an issue? We're pretty far along in the IPv6 game for something like this to be a problem.

Comment: If you get no luck with this answer, try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/759540/4246

Comment: On my just-installed Vagrant Ubuntu 16.04.4, this still works. Amazing. I thought I had a local networking problem. I guess my Comcast connection prefers IPv6 but ubuntu.com prefers IPv4.

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Comment: this worked for me!

Comment: Works on Mint 18.3. It solves delay problems with Driver Manager and Software Manager as well.

Comment: Also works for ubuntu 17.10!

Answer (score 16):

### Solution:

I figured out the problem. I had to disable IPv6 connectivity, as The Lord Of Time pointed out.

Running the following command in Terminal tells if IPv6 is enabled or not:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`

`0` means its enabled, while `1` means its disabled.

To disable IPv6 from within Terminal, enter the following:

```
echo "#disable ipv6" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

Re-run the first command, and it should be `1` now.

Comment: I don't have that file...

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is **not** a solution. It's a workaround. We need IPv6 and disabling it is definately not recommended. The correct solutions are either forcing APT to use ipv4 only, or setting the precendence as shown in the top solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to modify apt-get, then you can force IPv4 with:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

To make the setting persistent, create the file 99force-ipv4 in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/.

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

Put the following contents in it:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

Save the file, and you're good to go. If you want to force IPv6 instead, change the 4 to 6 in the file name and settings. To choose between one of them, test with the fast method and see which works better.