# Problems with updating Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, ipv6

when i call `sudo apt-get update` the process stops at `98% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)]` and nothing else happens. i've already done [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272796/connecting-to-archive-ubuntu-com-takes-too-long) because of the IPv6 problems reported, but i did not help. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 and use Gnome 3. I've waited 10 minutes to let the update finish, but it didn't.
Here is the full update output:

```
hag@hag-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for hag: 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages           
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages         
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex 
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en             
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en               
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
98% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)]
```

EDIT: ok, i enabled IPv6 again. When i press reload in the Synaptic Package Manager it stucks at Downloading file 115 of 115 for ever. when i press Cancel it says

> Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/Release.gpg
>   Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

EDIT: i can also `ping security.ubuntu.com` without any problems

```
PING security.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=29.7 ms
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=31.5 ms
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_req=3 ttl=49 time=29.5 ms
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_req=4 ttl=49 time=30.1 ms
64 bytes from obake.canonical.com (91.189.92.200): icmp_req=5 ttl=49 time=29.2 ms
^C
--- security.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.282/29.950/31.598/0.808 ms
```

Comment: Did you reboot after you performed the actions in the solution on disabling IPv6? Either way, you should not disable IPv6 to fix this, and moreover, `apt-get` should time out on this, it should never take 10 minutes! So I guess there's more to it here.

Comment: yes, i rebooted. how can i debug/log what is happening during the  `apt-get`?

Comment: Or he could check if changing the `security.ubuntu.com` part for a IP could work. In this case you can use `host security.ubuntu.com` then replace any instance for the IP in his `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @Braiam i can ping `security.ubuntu.com` so this should not change anything!?

Comment: That's because you are not using ipv6 anymore. You should be able to update now.

Comment: @Braiam No, i already enabled IPv6 again by removing the lines inserted in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. And the problem still remains.

Comment: Peter, the pings you have made were done using IPv4.

Comment: You have to use `ping6` to ping using IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be patient, (an hour or two patient). There could be an error getting the siganature , you just wait while you see a movie, and then you could probably get the error (that i guess that is (cannot conect) ). 
After that you have to search it on your `source.list`, delate it and search for the new one.

**I recomend this page to update your source list**

http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

---

Be patient, a looootttt patient :)