# apt-get install isc-dhcp-server command is not working in ubuntu 14.04 server version

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to install dhcp server in my server machine. above mentioned command is not working. below snap shows the error

Comment: fail to fetch from au.archive.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the package `isc-dchp-server`, and it worked fine. I had problems with connecting to archive.ubuntu.com myself earlier, and that was related to ipv6.

This will keep ipv6 enabled, but ipv4 will be prioritized over ipv6: (taken from [connecting to archive.ubuntu.com takes too long](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272796/connecting-to-archive-ubuntu-com-takes-too-long))

```
sudo nano /etc/gai.conf
```

Then uncomment this line, by removing the `#`:

```
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```

Let me know how it works out for you!