# Problem with IPv6 sudo apt-get update/upgrade

Tags: networking, apt, upgrade, updates, dns

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 Beta 2 at the moment and every time I try to update at home via `sudo apt-get update` or upgrade trough `sudo apt-get upgrade` I wont get any feedback. Even installing of anything will have the same result. It will just "hang up" on `0% while fetching data`.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for niclas: 
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::11)] [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b)]
```

I have no idea how to solve the problem. I already tried to `ping6 archive.ubuntu.com` with 100% packet loss while just ping wont have any loss.

I changed the DNS-Server (IPv4 & IPv6) to Google's one no solution either.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this post on Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method)?  It seems to me that it can 'force' IPv4 and not IPv6, though I haven't tested.

Comment: That might work thank you. Can you explain where in sudo apt-get update I have to put the AcquireIpv4? :S I am relativly new to Linux

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> Thanks to [this Unix and Linux post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method) by [mmoya on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5576/mmoya) for the answer.

We can try and force `apt` to use IPv4 instead.

Try this command set, based off the information in the aforementioned link:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true upgrade
```

This should force IPv4 in place of IPv6.

---

You can make this persistent for all `apt-get` in the future (so you don't have to provide the arguments to make this work) by doing the following (also from the other U&L post):

```
echo 'Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4
```

This will make a configuration file for `apt` and `apt-get` to parse, which will then include the `ForceIPv4 true` options going forward for all `apt-get` runs.

Comment: Okay so I just tried your last suggestion. Is that one here normal? niclas@ThinkPad:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for niclas: 
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: Do you have a package manager open, or another update process (such as automated updates) running in the background?  Something is currently using the apt lists, so it's eitiher `dpkg` or another `apt`/`apt-get`, or a package manager (Ubuntu Software Center, for example) or automatic updates

Comment: Other answers mentioned changes to `/etc/gai.conf`, but did not work out. This did though. Not sure why gai.conf doesn't.

Comment: Great thanks, but this still doesn't explain why it doesn't work over IPv6.  Why can't Canonical just fix this server?

Comment: @AdamSpiers It very likely doesn't have to do with Canonical servers.  In many more frequent cases it has to do with "bad" IPv6 handling on wherever your system is.  This happens to me frequently at my home where IPv6 is "available" from the ISP but is not configured internally on the network or is otherwise being filtered.  Forcing IPv4 usually solves that problem.

Comment: @ThomasWard Definitely not in my case - [my ISP is a world leader in IPv6 which has been providing an IPv6 service for over 14 years](http://aa.net.uk/news-2012-08-ipv6.html), during which time they have vigorously tested compliance of devices at every hop of the network path, in many cases pushing hardware and software vendors to fix breakages.

Comment: Definitely this problem consists further and it must be caused by archive.canonical.com and ipv6. For me it occurs always while trying downloading flashplugin-installer:amd64 via ipv6. This takes up to 10 minutes to get connection but works then.

Comment: @AxelRichter use a different mirror then, different mirrors are faster or slower sometimes.