# Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80

Tags: server, upgrade, updates

This issues had been in my life for 2 weeks and I was unable to figure it out.

My domain name was hosted by 1&1 and my website is hosted by my own Ubuntu 18.04. I have no issue to ping anywhere and my website has no issue to visit.

However I can't update or upgrade my Ubuntu server with the following error message: 
my nameserver shows this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Thank you in advance for help.

```
sudo -E apt-get update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::1                                                                                        1). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to ar                                                                                        chive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreach                                                                                        able) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:800                                                                                        1::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection t                                                                                        o archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unr                                                                                        eachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162), connection                                                                                         timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.24), connection                                                                                         timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149), connectio                                                                                        n timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.31), connectio                                                                                        n timed out
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/759524/problem-with-ipv6-sudo-apt-get-update-upgrade

Comment: I tried both, none worked. same issue same results. I recently removed the UFW. and i use an iptables as below. this issue came after the ufw removal. is there something wrong with my iptables? the iptables is too long to post as comment