# Ubuntu 20.04 on server: 'apt-get update' reports that it fails. Cannot reach archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates

Looking around these forums and elsewhere I find that this is a common issue, however the proposed solutions have not been helpful and thus I ask in hopes that someone might be able to have the right solution.

I have an old IBM M2 server with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I have tested that I can use `curl` and `ping` to different sources like Google and that works just fine. My server can clearly see the internet. But I cannot ping the ubuntu servers, however.

I've tried with `ufw` enabled and disabled and it's the same either way.

The following errors show up when I attempt `sudo apt-get update`:

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (130.225.254.116), connection timed out

Err:2 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Err:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Err:4 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done

W: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (130.225.254.116), connection timed out

W: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

W: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

W: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to dk.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:878:346::116). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have not set up any sort of proxy. This server is running out of the box settings and so I am confused as to why `apt-get update` (and also `apt-get install` seems to have similar issues) just doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What solutions did you try? Have you tried forcing IPv4 as suggested in [Problem with IPv6 sudo apt-get update/upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759524/problem-with-ipv6-sudo-apt-get-update-upgrade)

Comment: @steeldriver I have tried what you said there and it still fails. I have also tried with and without ufw as well as adding nameservers to the config files. None of them worked :/

Comment: Turns out I cannot ping dk.archive.ubuntu.com from any computer. It just doesn't work. However I can ping some of the others like in. and en. so I switched to en.archive.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that `dk.archive.ubuntu.com` was just straight up inaccessible. I tried on computers and server and all. So after pinging a couple of the different archives, I manually edited `/etc/apt/sources.list` and switched my settings to use the `en.archive.ubuntu.com` servers instead, which solved my problem.

The following command will automatically change the `dk.archive.ubuntu.com` archive to the `en.archive.ubuntu.com` archive:

```
sudo sed -i 's/dk.archive.ubuntu.com/en.archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and finally:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: How did you do that? I have the same issue right now.

Comment: @Whir See the updated instructions.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Had same problem but with it.archive